# git submodule from local folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

Have a git repo named `parent-repo`. It has folder `lib` with libraries. 'lib/one' is under control of `parent-repo`. And now I want to make git to recognize `lib/one` as git submodule of `parent-repo`.

```
cd lib/one
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

I think next steps are

0. `cd parent-repo`
1. untrack `lib/one`
2. register `lib/one` as submodule
3. stage and commit.

Please clear next steps with git commands if it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Current solution is create dedicated repo from that sources out of `parent-repo`. Move `lib/one` out of of `parent-repo` and create new git repository.

```
mv 'lib/one' ../one
cd ../one && git init && git add . && git commit -m 'first commit
# git remote add ... && git push
```

then

```
cd parent-repo
git submodule add --name one file:///path/to/one lib/one  # for example in windows file:///D/myrepos/one, file://../one relative path disallowed
git add lib/
git commit -m 'lib/one is submodule now'
```